# Having issue pulling rabbitmq windows docker image

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to pull [this image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gsxsolutions/rmq-nano/) of RabbitMQ Windows docker and getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\my\path> docker pull gsxsolutions/rmq-nano:3.7.7
3.7.7: Pulling from gsxsolutions/rmq-nano
407ada6e90de: Extracting [==================================================>]  81.04MB/81.04MB
5ebc0041967d: Download complete
90ff54195cd3: Download complete
3b6503dee8a9: Download complete
a4ded2b8a662: Download complete
ffb9541f045d: Download complete
b3c3ad90f63f: Download complete
5af9b6d2d080: Download complete
06e56edb1047: Download complete
34f10ae53c0a: Download complete
8f13a439b5f8: Download complete
3a464506cfef: Download complete
ce4e1b97b699: Download complete
a2fcf9e9992b: Download complete
ff0476c572ba: Download complete
ce33946ddc63: Download complete
failed to register layer: re-exec error: exit status 1: output: ProcessUtilityVMImage \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\bc291da2a27fd5296c47d495edc3c7e605046b0d3de0adfb605e8368c0d009af\UtilityVM: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Doing some searching online doesn't reveal much. I cleared out all my other images and tried again and that didn't work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hopes that this will help some other poor soul coming this way, my solution was to upgrade Windows 10.  I was previously running on Windows 10 version 1607 and hadn't bothered to check my windows updates.  Updating to Windows 10 version 1803 (at the time of this writing) fixed my issue.  In addition, instead of just running:

```
docker pull gsxsolutions/rmq-nano
```

It seems to want you to specify some version:

```
docker pull gsxsolutions/rmq-nano:3.7.7
```

This worked for me.